# Understanding converting big endian to/from string

Tags: javascript, string, bit-manipulation

Looking at these implementations, I am wondering if one could explain the reason behind the specific operations. Not coming from computer science, I am not sure why these decisions were made.

```
function binb2rstr(input) {
  var str = []
  for (var i = 0, n = input.length * 32; i < n; i += 8) {
    var code = (input[i >> 5] >>> (24 - i % 32)) & 0xFF
    var val = String.fromCharCode(code)
    str.push(val)
  }
  return str.join('')
}

function rstr2binb(input) {
  var output = Array(input.length >> 2)

  for (var i = 0, n = output.length; i < n; i++) {
    output[i] = 0
  }

  for (var i = 0, n = input.length * 8; i < n; i += 8) {
    output[i >> 5] |= (input.charCodeAt(i / 8) & 0xFF) << (24 - i % 32)
  }

  return output
}
```

What I understand so far are:

1. `i += 8` is for iterating through bytes.
2. `0xFF` is 255, which is `2^8 - 1`, so 1 byte.
3. 32 which is the size of a *word*, or 4 bytes
4. `|` is bitwise OR, `<<`, `>>>`, and `&` are likewise bit operators.
5. The `%` modulus keeps the value within that max value of `x = x % max`.

What I don't understand is:

1. `i >> 5`, how that was picked.
2. `& 0xFF`, how that was picked.
3. `24 - i % 32`, where the 24 came from.
4. `var code = (input[i >> 5] >>> (24 - i % 32)) & 0xFF`, how the character code is computed from that.
5. `input.length >> 2`

Wondering if this is just a standard computer science function because it's hard to tell where these variables come from and how this was learned. It seems like these values must be a standard algorithm based on byte length but I can't tell how to get there with these open questions. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code consists of some pretty clever bit-fiddling based on 32-bit values.
But let's work on your points:

> 1. i >> 5, how that was picked.

This divides `i` by 32 --- corresponding to the `n = input.length * 32` overall length. Considering the whole algorithm this means that one value is processed four times `(0,8,16,24)` before selecting the next `input` value.

> 2. & 0xFF, how that was picked.

This simply selects the lowest 8-bit of a n-bit value.

> 3. 24 - i % 32, where the 24 came from.

This relates to `i += 8`. The `i % 32` indicates four different iterations (32/8=4) which are `temp= (0, 8, 16, 24)`. So `24-temp` results in `(24,16,8,0)`.

> 4. var code = (input[i >> 5] >>> (24 - i % 32)) & 0xFF, how the character code is computed from that.

```
1. 1st iteration: i=0 ;24-0=24; input[0] >>> 24 & 0xFF =     highest byte of input[0] shifted to lowest
2. 2nd iteration: i=8 ;24-8=16; input[0] >>> 16 & 0xFF = 2nd highest byte of input[0] shifted to 2nd lowest
3. 3rd iteration: i=16;24-16=8; input[0] >>>  8 & 0xFF = 2nd lowest  byte of input[0] shifted to 2nd highest
4. 4th iteration: i=8 ;24-24=0; input[0] >>>  0 & 0xFF =     lowest  byte of input[0] shifted to highest
```

This was the Big-Endian-Conversion.
The next iteration has `i=32` and starts the next iteration  `input[32/32]`=`input[1]`.

Overall this algorithm shifts the 32-bit code to the right and masks the lowest 8-bit to be used as a CharCode by `String.fromCharCode(code)`.

The last one is from a different algorithm and so `input.length >> 2` simply does a `division by 2` discarding the possible rest of 1.

---

Concerning your last question:

> It seems like these values must be a standard algorithm based on byte length but I can't tell how to get there with these open questions.

This is far from a standard algorithm. It is just a clever bit-manipulation *based on bytes*.

In assembler this code would be even easier to understand.
There is even one instruction called [`BSWAP`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/BSWAP.html) to swap between 32-bit Big-Endian and Little-Endian values in a register.